# keep track of friends and number of days not spoken to, dynamic memory location

Tags: c++

Write a program that lets users keep track of the last time they talked to each of their friends. Users should be able to add new friends (as many as they want!) and store the number of days ago that they last talked to each friend. Let users update this value (but don't let them put in bogus numbers like negative values). Make it possible to display the list sorted by the names of the friends of by how recently it was since they talked to each friend.

This is the code I have written so far. I'm having problems with the array size not growing as it should do. Also I'm unsure about how to go about list the names with numbers of days out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int *growArray (int * friends, int * size)
{
    *size *= 2;
    int *new_friends = new int[*size];
    for (int i=0; i < *size; i++) {
        new_friends[i] = friends[i];
    }
    delete [] friends;
    return new_friends;
}

string *growArray2 (string * name1, int * size)
{
    *size *= 2;
    string *new_name2 = new string[*size];
    for (int i=0; i < *size; i++) {
        new_name2[i] = name1[i];
    }
    delete [] name1;
    return new_name2;
}

void printArray (string *name1, int *friends,int size, int element_set)
{
    cout << "the total size of the array is: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Values in the array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < element_set; ++i)
    {
        cout << name1[i] << "[" << i << "] = " << friends[i] << " days since you last spoke to them" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string exit = "X";
    string name;
    int noDays;
    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 4;
    int *friends = new int[size];
    string *name1 = new string [size];
        cout << "Please enter your friends name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Please enter no of days you last spoke to them" << endl;
        cin >> noDays;
    while(true) {
        if (size == next_element+1) {
            friends = growArray(friends, &size);
            name1 = growArray2(name1, &size);
        }
        friends[next_element] = noDays;
        name1[next_element] = name;
        next_element++;
        printArray(name1, friends, size , next_element);
        cout << "Please enter your friends name or X to exit" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        if (name == exit) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Please enter no of days you last spoke to them" << endl;
        cin >> noDays;

        }
        delete name1;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own primitive version of `vector`?

Comment: Is this an class exercise in memory management? If not then use std::vector

Comment: To make `User` sortable. Just define the `bool operator<(User const& lhs, User const& rhs)`. Now you will be able to sue `std::sort` on any container of User.

Comment: This code is definitely not off topic as `It works`. Admittedly not very well but it runs and needs a review.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have made edits up top as suggested. The reason for not using vectors is because I am currently working through an e-book which has not covered that topic yet so I am guessing I am not supposed to use them. @LokiAstari this is the chapter on dynamic memory allocation and pointer to pointers. So maybe I should use a pointer to pointer? I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the "growArray" function will never be called since you put it inside an if block that runs only once. when the if statement is evaluated your size is 10 and your next_element+1 is 1 and you never check for (size == next_element+1) again.

Answer (score 2):

A few considerations here. Probably the most important is: Don't write your own low-level data structures. It is difficult to do correctly and the standard library has lots of choices. In this case, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) seems like the best choice (in fact, it grows its underlying data store in the same way, by doubling its size when it runs out of room).

If for some reason you had to implement your own version of `vector`, you should implement it as a class, not as a bunch of free functions. Another general rule is

> Guideline: Don’t use explicit new, delete, and owning * pointers, except in rare cases encapsulated inside the implementation of a low-level data structure.

as Herb Sutter puts it in [his excellent article about smart pointers](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/). There are a number of reasons, including that it's easy to add bugs when passing around raw pointers and that exception safety is an issue when calling `new`.

Another error, as [Dima](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/26433/dima) points out, is that you are calling `growArray` outside your `for` loop.